# How to start object mapping mode in Jubula?

Tags: automated-testing, gui, eclipse, jubula

I am trying [Jubula](http://eclipse.org/jubula/) to automate test cases.

I have connected to UAT agent and started. But, Start object mapping mode is not clickable. I created test case and added component but I don't map with aut(application under test).

How to start object mapping mode in Jubula?

Answer (score 3):

The prerequisites for starting the object mapping mode are:

- project is created and opened
- a connection has been made to the AUT Agent (if this is successful, the "Stop AUT Agent" button on the toolbar will be enabled)
- an AUT has been configured via the project properties
- the AUT has been started. Your AUT is successfully started if the AUT can be seen to be running, and it is listed in the "Running AUTs" view.

Typical problems can be:

- when working with RCP AUTs: the prerequisite steps to configure the application have not been made. These are documented in the user manual and mentioned in this FAQ: 
  http://testing.bredex.de/faqs/how-do-i-configure-jubula-to-test-rcp-applications.html

  - One of the required steps mentioned above has been missed.

Comment: Thank you for replying Alex. I have solved. I want to test a map application and map layer is GIS manager. How to  click on any GIS manager object?

Comment: My assumption is that the GIS objects might not be supported out of the box. You can read in the Developer Manual (1) about how to extend Jubula. 
(1) http://testing.bredex.de/documentation-download.html